# boot Debian default kernel with lilo results in kernel panic

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, kernel-panic, lilo

I have server with Debian 10 installed.

I am using custom kernel, with `lilo` boot loader. This is my `/etc/lilo.conf`:

```
boot=/dev/sda
root=/dev/sda1
map=/boot/map

lba32

prompt
timeout=50

default=linux

image=/boot/vmlinuz-5.10.46
label=Linux
read-only
append="rootfstype=ext4 net.ifnames=0 loglevel=4 console=tty0 2"
```

Now I want to boot the default Debian distribution kernel. I have installed the debian kernel image:

```
apt-get install linux-image-amd64
```

and added the entry to `/etc/lilo.conf`:

```
image=/boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-17-amd64
label=4.19.0-17-amd64
initrd=/boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-17-amd64
read-only
append="rootfstype=ext4 net.ifnames=0 loglevel=4 console=tty0 2"
```

However, when I boot this kernel, I get kernel panic.

[image]

**How can I boot default debian distribution kernel with lilo?**

Comment: distribution kernels have everything as possible built as module.Are you sure the needed modules are included in the initramfs? eg: sata/scsi/ahci support, ext4 support etc.

Comment: @A.B - I am not sure. I just installed the package as described above. How can I check, or what do I need to do to make sure the initrd file has all the modules?

Comment: I didn't find an exact Q/A telling how to unpack it but there are a few. You should extract back the content of the initramfs to check. This content depends on additional "content" like µcode patch. Usually I do (in a new dir) `(cpio -i -m ; gunzip | cpio -i -m) < /boot/initrd.img-someversion` . You might have to remove the first cpio though depending on how it's built.

Comment: @A.B - I ran `update-initramfs`. Is this supposed to generate initrd with the needed drivers?